# how do you store data from a for loop into a variable for other calculations?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

I'm trying to store my sums into a variable to add up for a percentage between the years. Right now I'm stumped on how to do this. I searched for answers and tried a few things ,but with no luck yet. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to figure this out.I keep getting the memory location and not the value. I'm a college student so please bear with me. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's my code to review.

```
#define years 4
#define months 12
int main(void)
{
    float percentage [4];
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0, sum = 0;
    int time[] = {    2012,2013,2014,2015};
    int *value[years];
    const char* name[]= {"  JAN ", "FEB ", "MAR ", "APR ", "MAY ", "JUN ", "JUL  ","AUG ","SEP ","OCT ","NOV ","DEC "};
    int range[years][months] = {

        { 5626, 5629, 5626, 5606, 5622, 5633, 5647, 5656, 5673, 5682, 5728, 5728},
        { 5741, 5793, 5814, 5811, 5831, 5854, 5857, 5874, 5900, 5923, 5954, 5939},
        { 5999, 6020, 6062, 6103, 6115, 6128, 6169, 6194, 6219, 6233, 6256, 6301},
        { 6351, 6378, 6371, 6409, 6426, 6426, 6437, 6441, 6451, 6484, 6549, 6597}
    };

    printf(" YEAR  %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", name[0], name[1], name[2], name[3], name[4], name[5], name[6],name[7],name[8],name[9],name[10],name[11]);
    /* for(n=0; n < name; n++)
           printf("%s", name[n]); // code keeps crashing my program
    */
    for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        printf(" %i    ", time[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < months; j++)
            printf("%2i ", range[i][j]);
            printf("\n");

    }

    for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < months; j++)
            sum += range[i][j];
            printf("\n This is the sum of months for %i: %i", time[i], sum);


    }
    for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < months; j++)
            value[years] = sum;
            printf("\n%i", value);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In your very last for loop you set sum as 0 and never change it.  So you end up setting all values to 0.

Comment: Also in that last loop you forgot to use the [years]  brackets and index so that you print the value at that index.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look at that now.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  However, the problem with your commented-out loop is that you're comparing `n` to `name`, which makes no sense since `name` is an array.  Change the test to `n < months` to fix that loop.

Comment: More issues for your review. `value[years]=sum` is a buffer overflow as `years` is not a valid index (max valid index is `years-1`). `int *value[years]` that declares a pointer array but then you try to store `int` values. Perhaps you meant `int value[years];`.

Comment: I tried to use a pointer to store the values of the sums , but i kept getting the memory data displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `value` to an array of `int`s. It does not make sense to make `value` to be an array of pointers.

```
int value[years]; // Drop the *
```

You have the following block to compute the sum for each year.

```
for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
    for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < months; j++)
        sum += range[i][j];
        printf("\n This is the sum of months for %i: %i", time[i], sum);
}
```

However, the sum does not get stored. It gets overwritten for each year.

What you need to do is save the sum in `value`. Use:

```
for (i = 0; i < years; i++)
{
   value[i] = 0;
   for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < months; j++)
   {
      value[i] += range[i][j];
   }
   printf("\n This is the sum of months for %i: %i", time[i], value[i]);
}
```

After that, you don't need the last loop at all.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @RTriplett, you are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.